# MySQL Workbench: How to disable scanning of all tables during start?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We have a project with hundreds of DB tables. Every time I open MySQL Workbench or change DB it freezes for several minutes. All points to WB executing sequentially `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM {DB}.{TABLE}` on each table in DB during which time one cannot execute any queries and when trying to execute more queries the UI gets unresponsive.

I sometimes cross Great Firewall of China when accessing DB and the speeds are terrible ~15kB/s which amplifies the whole issue to the point I have to abandon WB. One cannot wait 10 minutes after each `use database;` statement...

*Is there a way I can switch DBs/open connections without having to wait that long before I can execute any queries?*

---

**More Info**

When I watch process list I see 4 Workbench DB connections open. One runs bunch of `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM {DB}.{TABLE}`, another one lists processes (since I use WB's Administration/Open Connections that does work) and 2 connections sits idle.

This is the WB debug output:

```
21:40:27 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Opened connection '...' to Source distribution version 5.6.21-69.0-log
21:40:28 [DB3][       GRT task]: Sending task "Live Schema Refresh Task" to dispatcher (don't wait)...
21:40:28 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Running task "Live Schema Refresh Task"
21:40:29 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Task "Live Schema Refresh Task" finished

-- Schema refresh started here
21:40:29 [DB3][SqlEditorSchemaTree]: Fetch schema contents for {DATABASE_HERE}
21:40:29 [DB3][       GRT task]: Sending task "Live Schema Fetch Task" to dispatcher (don't wait)...
21:40:29 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Running task "Live Schema Fetch Task"

-- Here I executed query "SELECT 1;" - it started spinning wheel...
21:40:45 [DB1][SQL Editor Form]: Executing SQL in editor: SQL File 4* (current statement only: yes)...
21:40:45 [DB3][       GRT task]: Sending task "execute sql queries" to dispatcher (don't wait)...
21:40:45 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Running task "execute sql queries"
21:40:45 [DB1][SQL Editor Form]: Background task for sql execution started
21:42:09 [DB2][            grt]: wb.form.showOptions finished in 67.86s

-- Schema refresh finished
21:42:36 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Task "Live Schema Fetch Task" finished
21:42:36 [DB3][SQL Editor Form]: Executing statement range: 0, 8...
21:42:36 [DB3][SQL Editor Form]: Determined statement type: 8
21:42:36 [DB3][SQL Editor Form]: Result will not be editable
21:42:36 [DB3][SQL Editor Form]: Running...
21:42:37 [DB2][ SqlEditorPanel]: Query successfully finished in editor SQL File 4*
21:42:37 [DB3][  GRTDispatcher]: Task "execute sql queries" finished

-- I got result of "SELECT 1;" 2 minutes later
```

**UPDATE**: I filled a bug with Oracle - so far it looks like no workaround is available and it severely limits functionality in certain scenarios. Vote it up by clicking "Affects Me" if you have the same problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99417

Comment: Do you use the latest WB version? The meta data fetching happens in a background thread, so it should not block the UI. Also, fetching happens only for the schema node that was expanded the first time.

Comment: Yes, I am using mysql-workbench-community 8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04 64bit downloaded from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/.

It does fetch schema always. Even when using "use {db}" SQL it does that.

I am using Debian Buster.

Comment: Sounds worthy of a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling code completion, which is the part of MySQL Workbench which needs all the meta data upfront:

[image]

The schema tree will still get the schema names and names of the objects of a schema, if it is made active or its node is expanded the first time.

#### Possible Workaround:

MySQL Workbench needs something to show in the schema tree and having the DB objects listed is one of the major advantages over any command line client. But you could limit the DB object loading to the absolute minimimum by never switching schemas. Then the delay would happen only once at connection start up and everything else should be fast then. If you really need more than one schema to work with use multiple connections to the same host, each using a different schema as default (can be set in the connection parameters).

Admittedly, this is not a perfect solution, but at least should allow you to work normally, once you got over the startup phase.

Comment: Good thinking! But unfortunately it didn't have any effect. I connect, I execute `SELECT 1;` in SQL editor and 2 minutes later I am presented with result.

Comment: Exactly what I did: #1 Disabled "Enable Code Completition in Editors", #2 Disabled in item "SQL Editor"  the "Restore expanded state of the active schema objects" option and  in "Sidebar" section unchecked all. No effect.

-> Same effect.

Comment: Maybe the workaround I added to my answer can help you?

Comment: This is what I am doing... I open all the connections I expect to use. The problem is that we have way too many databases and many times it is that unexpected urgent situation that needs swift action that is the major problem for me. Great China Firewall is also unreliable and SSH tunnels hang up so one needs to restart often...  But thanks for the tip. For most part it works but at the end I have to use also EMMA tool on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try disabling Query Caching, running
`SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0;`
should do the trick, if available.

Comment: This command instructs server-side database how to optimize queries. I identified the issue as client-side app issue so unless WB parses this command itself and modifies db probing behavior it should not have any effect on the issue I described. 

Am I missing here something?